# How to get datatable row object in knockout js

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want row object in my java controller through ajax call.

This is my view :

```
tableMarkup += '<td><a data-bind="click: function () { $root.deleteRow($data); }" class="new-tltip delete-icon delete-map-icon" title="Delete" data-stval="1"></a></td>';
```

This is my function :

```
self.deleteRow = function(data) {
    debugger;

        $rootScope.loading();
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: $("#rootConxt").val()+"/gobalMapping/deleteGlobalMapDetails",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. At least for me, I have no idea what you're  asking help for

Comment: i m not sure my code is right or wrong, but i simply wants, when i click on button,button present at data table row, so when i click on button i want that row data/object in my deleteRow function.

Answer (score 0):

you can receive the data in your controller as a JavaScript or a JSON object.
there you can use them to convert to java object using classes like JSONObject or Jackson Mapper API.

post your data like this :

`ko.toJS(data);`  or 
`ko.JSON(data)`;

Comment: i m not sure my code is right or wrong, but i simply wants, when i click on button,button present at data table row, so when i click on button i want that row data/object in my deleteRow function.